# How to deauthorize an iPad 2?

Tags: itunes, ipad, apple-id

I used to own an iPad 2. I didn't much care for it, so I gave it to my sister as a gift. She lives in a different state.

I thought I removed any/all of my account info from it. But apparently my Apple ID is still stuck on it.

**How do I deauthorize it, so my sister can put her Apple ID onto it?** Is resetting the iPad 2 to factory settings the only way?

I obviously do not *physically* have it in front of me anymore. I don't mind passing my password to my sister, and having her sign into her local iTunes with my account to deauthorize it, but she says that to do that she would lose all her current iTunes data.

Also, if there is a way to deauthorize it without a reset, will the apps I purchased still be accessible to her on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have her go to Settings.app > Store - if your account is signed in, sign out. She can then sign in to her own account. Any apps you've downloaded using that account will still prompt for that account's password when they need updating, though.

Comment: She tells me that when she connects it to her Macbook Pro, that it's still listed as my iPad.

Comment: As in, the name shows up as "Sunpech's iPad" in the device listing on the left? If so, she can click on the name in the sidebar, and it will be editable. If iTunes is giving her the 'this iPad is synced with another library' message, then it's because her machine isn't authorized to playback that content. 'Deauthorizing' it in this sense would involve syncing it to her computer, which would delete any of the content from your account. Or, she can authorize your account on her computer. In short, to keep using your apps, she'll need to be authorized.